# Open two programs and split the windows vertically

Tags: batch

I run below batch file to open file explorer and run the batch. I want to split the windows to occupy half of the screen. However they did not split the windows half and half. Please advise how to modify the .vbs script.

**Batch file**

```
@echo off
echo Manual Install
explorer ,
ping /n 4 localhost>nul 2>&1
wscript "%~dp0SidebySide.vbs"
set /p "dri=WindowsInstallDrive: "
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:%dri%:\sources\sxs /NoRestart
goto end
```

**SidebySide.vbs**

```
dim objShell
set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.TileVertically
set objShell = nothing
```

[image]